# Role of decrement operator in the following statement?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Going through a solution for a problem I'm trying to solve and I am not able to understand how the decrement operator works in the following statement.

```
if (--degree[j] == 0) bfs.add(j);
```

Comment: It decrements the operand and returns the decremented value. As documented.

Answer (score 0):

Write some simple code to confirm what you think

```
int arr[] = {1};
    
if (-- arr[0] == 0) {
    System.out.println("true");
}

// and again
if (-- arr[0] != 0) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

**output**

```
true
true
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @sandeepvenkat Please consider to upvote/accept this answer

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean thrown = false;
            int[] arr = new int[]{1};

            --arr[0];
            out.println("true");

            if (-- arr[0] != 0) out.println("true");
    }
}
```

**Output **

```
true
true
```

Comment: What is this intended to show? What is `thrown` for? Why are you printing `true` twice? Doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).